# How to write a file to Google Cloud Storage directly without saving it in my application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to write an HTML file into Google Cloud Storage without saving the file in my node application. I need to create a file and immediately upload to the Cloud Storage.
I tried using `fs.writeFileSync()` method, but it creates the file in my application and I  do not want that.

```
const res = fs.writeFileSync("submission.html", fileData, "utf8");
GCS.upload(res, filePath);
```

I expect to save an HTML file in the Cloud Storage directly. Could you please recommend the right approach to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I believe is to use the `file.save` method that wraps `createWriteStream`, so this should work.

```
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const myBucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket');

const file = myBucket.file('my-file');
const contents = 'This is the contents of the file.';

file.save(contents, function(err) {
  if (!err) {
    // File written successfully.
  }
});

//-
// If the callback is omitted, we'll return a Promise.
//-
file.save(contents).then(function() {});
```

Comment: See also this sample/documentation ... https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-storage